# sliding window on a python image

Tags: python, sliding-window

I want to transform this matlab code to python:

```
images = []; 
foreach image in images:
     features = [];
     windows = extractWindows(image,size=(30,30),stride=(30,30));
     foreach window in windows:
          featureVector = extractFeatures(window);
          features.append(featureVector);
     saveAsCSV('image_name_features.txt',features);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```py
def sliding_window(image, stepSize, windowSize):
  for y in range(0, image.shape[0], stepSize):
    for x in range(0, image.shape[1], stepSize):
      yield (x, y, image[y:y + windowSize[1], x:x + windowSize[0]])

def extractFeatures(window):
  # fast? sift? orb? or something?
  return features

images = []
for image in images:
  features = []
  windows = sliding_window(image, 30, (30, 30))
  for window in windows:
    featureVector = extractFeatures(window)
    features.append(featureVector)

  numpy.savetxt('image_name_features.txt', feautres, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: @frank97 please select the answer :)

Comment: I want to load an image on this code and extract features with sift method. Can you give me an example?